# Why does the AIR bot fail to see the correct colour?

Tags: python, bots, pyautogui

This is an attempt from a beginner to make an AIR bot for Dead By Daylight blood webs. in my code, I explicitly try to only click on the color with an RGB of 255,255,255 however for some reason or other when the program is run it will click on colors with different RGB values, such as 128,128,128, or sometimes just something completely different (it also breaks a few times but I just wanna tackle this one problem at a time)

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
time.sleep(2)
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(1.3)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(250,200,750,750))
    width, height = pic.size
    for x in range(0,width,10):
        for y in range(0,height,10):
            r,g,b = pic.getpixel((x,y))
            if r == 255 and g == 255 and b == 255:
                click(x+250,y+200)
                time.sleep(0.05)
                break
```

Comment: Could it possibly be because you click at `(x+250,y+200)` rather than where you actually check the colour at `(x,y)`?

Comment: Also please read [mre].

Comment: @Julien unfortunately not as 250 and 200 are the width and height on my screen at which the code starts at and scans for white, also yes I will read it, thank you.